# How do I link i386 code fragment into an x86_64 elf?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, cross-compiling, elf

When assembling using GNU assembler, I can use the `--x32` command-line option to make it output 32-bit code into a x86_64 object file. I can then happily link it with 64-bit code produced by gcc and the two see each other's symbols.

However, I'd like to write most of the 32-bit code in C instead of assembly. Can I make gcc output 32-bit code into x86_64 object files?

Comment: I know nothing about this but intuition and a quick Google suggests it's not necessarily trivial. Have a glimmer through https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/x32 to see whether I'm on the right track.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, thanks, that's an unfortunate clash of names, that lib is still x86_64, except with short longs and pointers.

Comment: How do you tell the processor it's now running 32-bit code, anyway?

Comment: @avakar: What other differences are you looking for? Your program still has to be written in the correct instruction set; there's no way around that

Comment: The CPU will start in 32-bit mode, but I'll be switching it to 64-bit mode (from the 32-bit portion of the code) and then transferring control to the 64-bit code. Think kernel. As such, the two parts of the binary need to see each other's symbols. This is easy to do if I write the 32-bit portion in assembly, but I'd rather have C available.